# Hiding soft keyboard in a tablet application using angular

Tags: angular, hide, android-softkeyboard, tablet

Is there a function that I can use to hide the soft keaboard of a tablet as I am implementing my own virtual keyboard? Please send me solutions using angular. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hvtjjk-g9rhc9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html here is my application i want when i am on the tablet and enter the input field to deactivate the tablet soft keyboard and only allow my virtual keyboard to be  shown